# Dell laptop with Ubuntu preinstalled in India

Tags: dell

I am in India and want to buy a Dell laptop with Ubuntu but on dell site they dont have an option for Ubuntu as an operating system. Are there no Ubuntu laptops available for users in India?

Comment: The best you can do is purchase a Dell laptop, and before using it, ask for a refund on the Windows, because you yet havent agreed to the terms in the EULA.

Comment: Will this really work? I'd definitely like to try.

Comment: Just as an FYI: Dell does not provide Ubuntu-preinstalled systems for sale.  They have globally ceased the support for selling ubuntu systems.

Comment: @LordofTime *Cough.* http://blog.canonical.com/2012/06/18/dell-extends-ubuntu-retail-into-india/

Comment: We i bought a dell laptop with out OS and then installed Ubuntu ...

Comment: @Optimus that is a waste of money - you're spending $100 ish on windowz...

Answer (score 1):

http://www.ubuntu.com/dell

http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=256

this two links might help you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know Dell does not sell Ubuntu/Linux laptops on their India portal as of now.

If you insist on a Dell Laptop then post purchase you can install Ubuntu on dual boot or completely replace Windows. If you are willing to look at other brands then some products are mentioned in on [this website](http://www.lug-iitd.org/List_of_laptop_with_preinstalled_GNU-Linux_in_India).

Answer (score 1):

Dell had a few [Vostro laptops that came with Linux](http://search.ap.dell.com/results.aspx?s=gen&c=in&l=en&cs=&k=vostro&cat=all&x=0&y=0). In this page, it says that Linux option will become available in April. You can search for Ubuntu on their Indian site and you will find some models Ubuntu 10.10.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked these out ? : http://www.flipkart.com/browse/computers/laptops/dell?filter=operating_system%3ALinux&_l=WKT4JijRHQ3kkLCn1ITPnw--&_r=veL4UGBD79Loyio3wH3Q+Q--&ref=4790a7fe-d7f6-4d94-a61d-d28b1a58be11

The site says linux, however does not mention which distribution it comes with.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to order via phone and ask for preinstalled Ubuntu on it?! I read and heard that Dell isn`t selling from online store, but you can order ubuntu based computers from a call.

Answer (score 1):

A startup [manaveeyam.in](http://manaveeyam.in) in Kochi started selling Ubuntu Laptops in southern India.

Answer (score 0):

A while back I purchased a Dell 1420n with Ubuntu installed. The only hardware difference with the 1420 that came with Windows was the WiFi card which for the Linux model was an Intel which is well supported with an open source driver. The Windows 1420 came with a Broadcom card which may be better supported currently.

Answer (score 0):

Manaveeyam Technologies trying to contribute in a small way by bringing Ubuntu based laptops in Kerala, India market - http://manaveeyam.in/category/products

Comment: Please disclose it if you are promoting your own products!

Answer (score 0):

Buy a laptop without any OS pre-installed and install Ubuntu yourself. Just make sure before purchasing that no component is dependent on proprietary drivers. eg: few graphic cards and wireless network cards etc.